# How to properly rotate ImageView that belongs to a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-imageview

I'm asking this question because I get a funny error by which I get two ImageView of my RecyclerView rotated when, in principle, I have only programmed it so that one does the rotation.

Background info: I have a total amount of 30 pictures that I uploaded to the drawable folder. They crashed my app when I run the code so I created a class to optimize them like the android developer guidelines advise:

```
public class ImagenOptimizada {


public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}


public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
}
```

This solved the `OutOfMemoryError`. But I still had the problem that some of the images I had uploaded appeared upside down (even though they appeared with the right orientation in desktop), so I decided to include the following code inside the `onBindViewHolder` method of the `RecyclerAdapter` class:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

int image_id = images[i];

viewHolder.album.setImageBitmap(ImagenOptimizada.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(viewHolder.album.getResources(), image_id, 250, 250));

if(image_id == R.drawable.img_2321 || image_id == R.drawable.img_2322 || image_id == R.drawable.img_2323 || image_id == R.drawable.img_2335 || image_id == R.drawable.img_2359 || image_id == R.drawable.img_2361) {

    viewHolder.album.setRotationX(180);

}


viewHolder.albumTitle.setText("Image: " + i);

}
```

This triggered a funny behavior as it did turn around the images I wanted but also other images with different ids too (I've realized it turns around two images, the one I want and another one, for each id that I give inside the if condition). And now I'm completely stuck because I don't know why this occurs.

Here is the complete code of RecyclerAdapter.java:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    private int[] images;


    public RecyclerAdapter(int[]images){
        this.images = images;

    }



    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView album;
        TextView albumTitle;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            album = itemView.findViewById(R.id.album);                                                  // R.id.album porque album es el id que dimos a la ImageView en image_and_text_layout.xml
            albumTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.album_title);                                       // R.id.album_title porque album_title es el id que dimos al TextView en image_and_text_layout.xml
        }
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_and_text_layout, viewGroup, false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        int image_id = images[i];

        viewHolder.album.setImageBitmap(ImagenOptimizada.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(viewHolder.album.getResources(), image_id, 250, 250));

        if(image_id == R.drawable.img_2321 || image_id == R.drawable.img_2322 || image_id == R.drawable.img_2323 || image_id == R.drawable.img_2335 || image_id == R.drawable.img_2359 || image_id == R.drawable.img_2361) {

            viewHolder.album.setRotationX(180);

        }


        viewHolder.albumTitle.setText("Image: " + i);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.length;
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private int[] images = {R.drawable.img_2321, R.drawable.img_2322, R.drawable.img_2323, R.drawable.img_2325, R.drawable.img_2326, R.drawable.img_2328,
            R.drawable.img_2329, R.drawable.img_2333, R.drawable.img_2335, R.drawable.img_2356, R.drawable.img_2358, R.drawable.img_2359, R.drawable.img_2360,
            R.drawable.img_2361, R.drawable.img_2363, R.drawable.img_2365, R.drawable.img_2366, R.drawable.img_2383, R.drawable.img_2390, R.drawable.img_2393, R.drawable.img_2394,
            R.drawable.img_2396, R.drawable.img_2397, R.drawable.img_2398, R.drawable.img_2454, R.drawable.img_2455, R.drawable.img_2456, R.drawable.img_2457,
            R.drawable.img_2458, R.drawable.img_2465};

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(images);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

Thank you in advance to those who take the time to answer. I'm very grateful because I'm a newcomer to programming and I'm studying on my own which makes it hard at times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RecyclerView` will reuse `ViewHolder`s that have scrolled off the screen, but it doesn't automatically reset them. So you might have an `ImageView` that you already applied a rotation to being used for an image you don't want rotated. The solution is to explicitly call `setRotation(0)` in that case. The easiest way to do that in your code is probably to add an `else` block to the `if` statement where you apply the rotation currently.

```
if(...) {
    viewHolder.album.setRotationX(180);
} else {
    viewHOlder.album.setRotationX(0)
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide code? Should it be a nested if-else?  Like: if (scrolledoff????) {setRotation(0)} else { if (image_id == ....){setRotationX(180)}}  ???

Comment: It's just an `else` case on the check you already have. I edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you @Brucelet. It did solve the problem. I have marked the answer as accepted. I have nonetheless searched on Google about "RecyclerView reset" in order to find a clear explanation about this behavior without any success. I would like to really understand what's going underneath to avoid future mistakes. What keywords do you recommend me to search online to get this explanation?